# Double simultaneously changing of the property fires only one propertyChanged event and second is ignored

Tags: xaml, xamarin, data-binding, uwp, binding

Double simultaneously changing of the view model property fires only one BindableProperty.PropertyChanged event and second is ignored.

Examples

```
VM.MyProperty = new Point[1];
VM.MyProperty = new Point[2];
//The BindableProperty.PropertyChanged will be called once.
```

-

```
VM.MyProperty = new Point[1];
await Task.Delay(75);
VM.MyProperty = new Point[2];
//The BindableProperty.PropertyChanged will be called twice.
```

--XAML

```
<cc:MyControl UpdatePoints="{Binding MyProperty}">
</cc:MyControl>
```

-- My custom control that bound to the MyProperty

```
    public static BindableProperty UpdatePointsProperty = BindableProperty.Create("UpdatePoints", typeof(Point[]), typeof(Scene), null, BindingMode.OneWay, propertyChanged: UpdatePointsChanged);
    public Defenition UpdatePoints
    {
        get { return (Defenition)GetValue(UpdatePointsProperty); }
        set { SetValue(UpdatePointsProperty, value); }
    }
    private static void UpdatePointsChanged(BindableObject bindable, object oldValue, object newValue)
    {
     //only once, but I need it twice
    }
```

Do I have the ability to config the delay to make the first code works the same as the second?

Comment: What is `MyProperty`? Is that a `IList` or `ICollection or ?

Comment: this is a property of a typical view model

Comment: I mean, what type it is?

Comment: I've fixed the question, please look it again! Thanks

Comment: I could not reproduce your issue with the above code could you share a mini sample ?